# Is there a way of updating a code first model without using migrations?

Tags: visual-studio, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

We're using Entity Framework 6.1.3. Recently I introduced the idea of using code first with existing database to my coworkers. Prior to that they've been using EDMX files for many years.

One important procedure that is followed where I work is developers must script the creation of tables. Eventually that's so we can hand those SQL scripts over to the DBAs, so they can apply the CREATE TABLE commands into the production database, which developers cannot touch.

However, the procedures by which I must abide makes I have with using using EF's migration with code first an issue. I've never used code first to create a database; those databases have always existed before starting any Visual Studio project to work with the database. From what I understand about updating an existing database from which model classes have been generated using code first, any update will create a Migrations folder in the Visual Studio project where the developer can make the necessary updates to table(s) in the database. That relies upon a Migration table in the database to coordinate the effort, track what's been updated and when, etc. This I  get from [this blog post](https://www.apress.com/us/blog/all-blog-posts/secular-trends-for-the-cloud/12097630). The issue is that I can't use migrations. The idea of that Migrations table won't fly here at work. It might even be dropped. (We're working with SQL Server.)

So, is there another way of updating the model class(es) in a code first with existing database without using EF's migrations?

Comment: so what's the advantage to use code-first in your case?

Comment: are developers using a shared database during developing time?

Comment: The advantage of using code first is that the EDMX file had become so corrupted when I tried to update it, but I couldn't fix it. I tried for a week, removing tables that were then, putting them back in multiple times. Then completely cleaning it out and pulling the database structure back in, multiple tries. That failed. Finally when I deleted the whole thing and used code first - it worked.

Comment: Yes, all developers use a shared database while developing.